# How do you scroll down scroll bar on windows form panel top to bottom automatically on form load?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am making pdf file opener on windows form using c#. I want to make windows form to grap pdf file name from specific folder to combobox and make combobox select next content in every x mins. But due to axAcroPDF1 using settings from adobe reader, I can't make single page fit full screen without keeping ratio which leaves huge unfilled area left and right without keeping the original aspect ratio. Since I can't get rid of it using adobe reader, I have to use fit to width but this make the page too big for reader and I can't view entire content without scroll down.

I've tried everything I can think of but I can't make it work.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"\c:\temp\"); 
            FileInfo[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf"); //Getting Text files

            var fileNames = Files.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)).ToList();
            comboBox1.DataSource = fileNames;
            timerset();
        }


        private void panel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void axSetting()
        {
            axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
            axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
            axAcroPDF1.setPageMode("none");
            axAcroPDF1.setShowScrollbars(false);
            axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");            
            axAcroPDF1.Show();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"c:\temp\ + comboBox1.Text + ".pdf");
            axAcroPDF1.src = @"c:\temp\" + comboBox1.Text + ".pdf";
            axSetting();
        }

        public void comboBoxSelect()
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < (comboBox1.Items.Count - 1))
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\");
                FileInfo[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf");

                var fileNames = Files.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)).ToList();
                comboBox1.DataSource = fileNames;
            }
        }

        public void timerset()
        {
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 10000; // in miliseconds            
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxSelect();
        }
```

How do I make the autoscroll on panel to scroll from top to bottom at load of each pdf file?

Comment: See this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollmargin?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Try to change these to be true:`AxAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(True)`  `axAcroPDF1.setShowScrollbars(True);`

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the [AutoScrollPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.AutoScrollPosition);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) like this.
You need to have this code in the `Shown()` event of a Form (not the `Load()`).

```
[ScrollableContainer].AutoScrollPosition = 
    new Point(0, [ChildControl].Height - [ScrollableContainer].Height);
```

The Size of `[ChildControl]` is of course greater than its `[ScrollableContainer]`'s.

It could also simply be:

```
[ScrollableContainer].AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, [ChildControl].Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it  now it works:
I changed these to be true:`AxAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(True)`  `axAcroPDF1.setShowScrollbars(True);` and I added   `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;` and `axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset.X, 10);
            axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset.Y, 10);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\");
            FileInfo[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf"); //Getting Text files

            var fileNames = Files.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)).ToList();
            comboBox1.DataSource = fileNames;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
       axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset.X, 10);
        axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(axAcroPDF1.AutoScrollOffset.Y, 10);
            timerset();
        }


        private void panel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void axSetting()
        {
            axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(true);
            axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
            axAcroPDF1.setPageMode("none");
            axAcroPDF1.setShowScrollbars(true);
            axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
            axAcroPDF1.Show();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"c:\temp\" + comboBox1.Text + ".pdf");
            axAcroPDF1.src = @"c:\temp\" + comboBox1.Text + ".pdf";
            axSetting();
        }

        public void comboBoxSelect()
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < (comboBox1.Items.Count - 1))
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                DirectoryInfo test = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\");
                FileInfo[] Files = test.GetFiles("*.pdf");

                var fileNames = Files.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)).ToList();
                comboBox1.DataSource = fileNames;
            }
        }

        public void timerset()
        {
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 10000; // in miliseconds            
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBoxSelect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. when if I change setShowToolbar(true); it's going to show unnecessary toolbars on top. also even if I set it true, it still won't autoscroll from top to bottom on new pdf load.